# NoMethodError undefined method mail for

Tags: actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-3.2

After setting up mailer (3.2.6) in Ruby on rails (3.2.6) I get this error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `mail' for #):

my user_mailer.rb looks like this:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "test@test.com"

  def activation_mail(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => user.mail, :subject => "Registration")
  end
end
```

I followed example provided here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

In configuration file I added this line: 
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
I also tried with :smtp and configuration for gmail.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem recently and rectified it by replacing:

```
def self.activation_mail()
```

with

```
def activation_mail()
```

Answer (score 3):

you should try replacing

```
def activation_mail(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => user.mail, :subject => "Registration")
  end
```

with

```
def activation_mail(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => @user.mail, :subject => "Registration")
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo error. Your **user.mail** doesn't exist. Maybe it should be **user.email** or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your "user" object you're passing is either 1) not instantiated correctly, or 2) an array instead of an individual User object

Answer (score 0):

I found that a typo in your mailer view can cause this problem. The error message is misleading.